# Spring Cloud Gateway MVC - state of play and resources

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cloud-gateway

Since Java 21 and the support of virtual threads, in future the reactive concept may become obsolete. And even if it does not, I would like to keep it as simple as possible
in my projects and architectures.
Recently I was pleasantly surprised that there is a MVC version of the Spring Cloud Gateway which is based on Spring MVC and tomcat/jetty. Unfortunately I could not migrate seamlessly the existing WebFlux gateway with its configuration of routes and filters to a MVC version of the gateway using version 4.1.0-RC1. I could not found documentation describing some alternative configuration format for MVC nor a migration guide.

Tehere is only two or three paragraphs in the official documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/spring-cloud-gateway-server-mvc.html explaining only the programmatic way of defining rules.

Please share if you have some knowledge of the state of this project. How both versions compare? Are there any lack of functionalities in one versus the other? Plans for the future and/or documentation.

Comment: Please check out this blog entry: https://sandipchitale.medium.com/spring-cloud-gateway-server-mvc-fn-6c8821395f22